# office365 Graph API to list only admin users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am trting to get all admin users from Office365 using Graph Users API. But userType of Admin users is null. Due to this I am not able to apply filter userType eq null. Is there any option to get only Admin users?
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=userType eq null

error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'userType' of resource 'User'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-07-01T17:14:04",
            "request-id": "resource-id"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to use roles rather than user types

Comment: is there any API to get the user roles?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with Microsoft Graph, moreso with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [unifiedRoleAssignments Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-list-roleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to list all the members of the `Global/Company administrator` role

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Kalyan. Is there any difference between directoryRoles/{id}/members and unifiedRoleAssignements API?

Comment: unifiedRoleAssignements and unifiedRoleDefinitions will succeed the directoryroles Api in future